# MongoDB equivelant to SQL "NOT LIKE" query

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT Currency, TransTime, AuthTime FROM MONIES WHERE Currency not like 'USD%';
```

If the SQL statement were simply a "LIKE" query, it would yield the following MongoDB statement

```
db.MONIES.find({
        "Currency": "USD%"
    }, {
        "Currency": 1,
        "TransTime": 1,
        "AuthTime": 1
});
```

Is this the proper query for a "NOT LIKE" equivalent? I think this is correct per [the documentation for the 'not' operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/), but I'd like to double check with Stackoverflow

```
db.MONIES.find({
        "Currency": { $not: { $like: 'USD%' } }
    }, {
        "Currency": 1,
        "TransTime": 1,
        "AuthTime": 1
});
```

Comment: there is no $like operator, I think you are looking for regular expressions http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The page you link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) actually has an example of what you want to do:

```
db.inventory.find( { item: { $not: /^p.*/ } } )
```

There is no `$like` operator, but MongoDB supports [regular expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

Comment: of course you need to replace 'item' with 'Currency' and replace 'p' with 'USD'